# Activemq topic subscribers heap memory leak - why are messages increasing?

Tags: jms, heap-memory, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

I have console application which connects to activemq topics. Abount 10 messages per second are published on each topic. After some time monitored that the application memory is increasing and when all the memory is used the application crashes. 
See the dump below. Why is ActiveMQTopicSubsctiber using so much heap? Also it is not visible but the ListEntries are about~14 000 (which means 14k messages).

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/404/amqmemoryproblem.png

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to possibly check for:

1. In your subscriber are you positive that the messages from the topic actually being consumed?
2. What is your [prefetchLimit](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) specified as?

Comment: 1) Yes, they are consumed, i know that for sure because they are logged in my onMessage method.

Comment: 2) I didn't specify any. Let me update my question... I need to consume messages in real time, so if some message become old (it it is not consumed after 1-2 seconds it is old) i don't need it, i need the newer messages which are came after it. I read about constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy, but i don't know how to set it (the producer and topic code is with service mix and my consumer is with java jms client). Is it possible to set constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy from broker uri like prefetchLimit from 2)?

Comment: After reviewing the last dump, i saw the same problem exists, even consuming was working almost 20 hours without a problem. So heap is increasing, but more slowly. I saw that the activemq topic dequeues the messages (by using constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy), but in the dump, the subscriber holds them i.e. the subscribed consumer does not drop consumed messages. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't recreate... with a quick test case of producing/consuming one million messages to a topic my heap levels off.  What version is your connection factory library?

Comment: I fixed the problem. TopicSession was created with CLIENT_ACK instead of AUTO_ACK. That is why the topic subscriber was keeping all messages, because they were not acknowledged.

Answer (score 0):

If holding messages in memory continues to be a problem, you should consider [configuring ActiveMQ to use file cursors](http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html#MessageCursors-ConfiguringCursors). The use of file cursors tells ActiveMQ to spool messages to disk instead of holding them in memory.